# Django None Type object is not callable

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to create an own usermodel, so I can login with email instead of using the username.
For this I used this tutorial:

https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

I used the AbstractBaseUser.
I also changed the model a bit, so I have some other fields.
The problem is, that when I send the request I get an error:

```
TypeError at /
'NoneType' object is not callable
Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:    3.1
Exception Type:    TypeError
Exception Value:
'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception Location:    ...\managers.py, line 18, in create_user
Python Executable:    ...\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:    3.8.5


Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
:arrow_forward: Local vars
...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, callback_kwargs) …
:arrow_forward: Local vars
...\views.py, line 7, in index
        user_creator.create_user(request.POST['email'], request.POST['username'], request.POST['displayname'], …
:arrow_forward: Local vars
...\managers.py, line 18, in create_user
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, display_name=display_name, extra_fields)
```

I think the problem is, that it doesn't know what the self.model in the manager.py at line 11 should be.

Here is my code:

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .managers import CustomUserManager

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_creator = CustomUserManager()
        user_creator.create_user(request.POST['email'], request.POST['username'], request.POST['displayname'],
                                 request.POST['password1'], request.POST['password2'])
    return render(request=request, template_name='index.html')
```

my manager.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, user_name, display_name, password, password2, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        if password != password2:
            raise ValueError(_('The passwords doesn\'t match'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, display_name=display_name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Used_Services(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(to='CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    porn_site = models.BooleanField()
    calendar = models.BooleanField()
```

my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

and my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Developer Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Site</h1>

    <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="text" name="displayname" placeholder="Displayname">
            <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat password">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What can I do?

Comment: why don't you use CustomUser instead of self.model if you already know what model it only use?

Comment: @Alviandoh 
So I need to take out the objects = CustomUserManager() in models.py? Because it tells me this: ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomUser' from partially initialized module 'main_site.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (...\models.py) when I try to import the CustomUser in managers.py